# tkinter runs in the background after quitting app related to matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter

I have a tkinter-based app, which was closing fine whenever the app closes (quit through window.destroy()). However, after I added a particular block of code, the app still closes but it is still running in the background. Prior to this, I had the same function but with a different variation of code and it closed fine. I narrowed it down to the specific block of code indicated by the block comments below. Any idea what could be causing this behavior?

```
def plot_graph(f):
fig_df_in = f
fig_df_in["Week Number"] = pd.to_datetime(fig_df_in["Available For Harvest"]).dt.isocalendar().week
fig_df_in = fig_df_in.loc[
    (fig_df_in["Week Number"] == window.current_week)]
fig_df_in = pd.pivot_table(fig_df_in, values="Acres", index="Available For Harvest", columns="RB#")

lf = ttk.Labelframe(table_frame)
lf.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=16, columnspan=12)

#problem seems to start here
ax = fig_df_in.plot(kind="bar")
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.set_size_inches(15.2, 4)
ax.set_xlabel("Harvest Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Acres")
plt.xticks(rotation="horizontal")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.10, 1), loc='upper right', borderaxespad=0)
# and end here

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=lf)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you're not properly closing the figure and the canvas object. If you dont close them correctly they'll keep running in the background

Try adding this at the end:

```
def on_closing():
    plt.close('all')
    window.destroy()
window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
```

This will be called when you close the window. It will first close all figures (using plt.close('all')) and then destroy the main window (using window.destroy()).